# How to count data within same table?

Tags: sql, count

I'm fairly new to SQL, struggling with this one.

I have a big table and i'm trying to count how many Shapes each Name has and how many Size Shapes each Name Has.

```
Name  Shape      Size  
Dave  rectangle  Small    
John  square     Medium  
Matt  rectangle  Small  
Dave  square     Large  
John  rectangle  Medium  
Matt  square     Small
```

I want the results to look like this

```
Name    Shape count Size count  
Dave    Square  3    large 1
```

Sorry if this isn't how this should be laid out - trying to automate some reports i'd otherwise have to manually do monthly.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: What does the sample data have to do with the specified result?  Where does the count "3" come from?  How is that related to "Dave"?

Comment: Does the specified result really match the given sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the two aggregations lined up by name.  If so, that is not a built-in ability in SQL, but you can construct the query to do what you want:

```
select name, max(shape) as shape, max(shape_cnt),
       max(size) as size, max(size_cnt)
from ((select name, shape, 0 as size_cnt, count(*) as shape_cnt,
              row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
       from t
       group by name, shape
      ) union all
      (select name, size, 0, count(*),
              row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
       from t
       group by name, size
      ) 
     ) nss
group by name, seqnum;
```